# Using iText and C# app, in WS 2012 R2, 64 Bits, I got this error, why?

Tags: itext, genexus

I'm developing an app with Genexus, that uses iText to render PDF.

And I get this error on Windows Server 2012, 64 bits.

> iTextSharp.text.DocumentException:C:\Windows\Fonts\BAR25IFH.TTF cannot be embedded due to license restrictions.

Same program on WS2003, 32bits , works fine.!

Best Regards

Comment: This means that the BAR25IFH.TTF included in WS2012 contains an attribute which indicates that this font may not be embedded in a document while the BAR25IFH.TTF included in WS2013 does not contain such a restriction.

Comment: Is there any info?, how do I get that license ?

Comment: This is a question to the developers of Genexus and to the way they use iText inside of their code. There is not a lot of thing that you can do and which would be legal. One thing you can try to do is removing that font at all from Fonts folder and see how Genexus works then.

Comment: Alternatively you can try to buy an unrestricted version of that font and replace the font in your fonts folder by that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should embed this font to your report, genexus has this property to be set  on PDFREPORT.INI file, like this

[Fonts Location (Sun)]
Microsoft Sans Serif= c:\windows\fonts\micross.ttf

have a look at this link

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27500,PDFReport.ini+file+format,

by default it doesn't embed fonts, you may already have this property set, if yes you can try to disable this property, so this error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was indeed the font file, I found anotjer BAR25IFH font, with permition to embbed.

And it works.

Regards